# Crontab who ping website using PHP on Debian server

Tags: php, debian, cron, ping

I made php script who ping a website, if i have a answer i do nothing, else i send email alert.
This is my code :

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
{  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
$url = 'http://www.website.com/';



if(urlExists($url) == true)
{
   exit('Website OK'."\n");
} else {

    $headers ='From: "Sembot"<noreply@website.com>'."\n"; 
    $headers .='Reply-To: noreply@website.com'."\n"; 
    $headers .='Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n"; 
    $headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'; 

    foreach ($destinataire as $dest) {
        echo 'Website DOWN'."\n";
        if(mail($dest, 'Sembot - Website DOWN', 'Website DOWN', $headers)) { echo 'email...'; }
    }

}
```

When i execute this file on a browser or with the console, the message is "Website OK" because the website is OK now. But when i create a crontab who execute my script each 5 minutes, i receive an email each 5min but the website is not dead... Did you know why ?

Comment: cron by default emails the output of a cron job to the owner of the job. if you don't want to the "ok" message getting mailed, then don't do any output in that code path.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this python script for a year. Works fine, everything you need to know to get it working in readme
https://github.com/bloodwithmilk25/ping-script

Answer (score -2):

I see you have a >= on next to your 200. This will be true every time since you have less then 300 and great or equal to 200.

Instead of this:

```
if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
    return true;  
} else {  
    return false;  
}
```

Try this:

```
if($httpcode > 200 && $httpcode < 300){  
    return true;  
} else {  
    return false;  
}
```

I simply just removed the equal.

Comment: From what I understand hes looking for a range no?

Comment: But 200 is success, >200 will only happen in very marginal scenarios. The proper range is 200-299, not 201-299. In other words, the problem is unrelated to this code, and this change will introduce a new bug.